# Unable to start MySQL on CentOS

Tags: centos, mysql

I've just installed a fresh version of MySQL on my CentOS machine. The problem I'm facing is that when I run this command:

```
# service mysqld start
```

I get in the console this error message:

> [ERROR] Can't change data directory owner to mysql

I'm not exactly sure what it means and how to fix it. Any comments and solutions are welcome. Thanks!

**EDIT**

It seems like I've fixed it with:

```
chown -R mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

But the very same command `# service mysqld start` now leads to another error message:

> [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting

Indeed, it has files, because during installation CentOS itself created this folder `/var/lib/mysql` and put some files in it. I did not do anything manually. So, what the heck is going on with CentOS and how to fix it?? Thanks!!

**EDIT**

It seems like either MySQL or CentOS has gone crazy. The catch is, if I delete all files from data directory, on start-up (when I run `#service mysqld start`) it creates a bunch of files in it, like `ca-key.pem` and other `.pem` files. So, it creates files and then throws an error, that the data directory is not empty. What a stupid behaviour! But how can I solve all this???

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with Kubernetes and MySQL 5.7 as well.

Adding the suggestion from [yosifki](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/186#issuecomment-229480846) to my container's definition got things working.

> A new ext4 disk partition is not usually empty;
> there is a lost+found directory, which mysql is known to choke on. You
> could try adding --ignore-db-dir=lost+found to the CMD to know for
> sure (from [mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_ignore-db-dir))

Here's an extract of my working YAML definition:

```
name: mysql-master
image: mysql:5.7
args:
  - "--ignore-db-dir=lost+found"
```

Here's an example snippet in docker-compose to clarify:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql-master:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: [--ignore-db-dir=lost+found]
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this trouble bootstraping percona xtradb.
Do:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
```

Then start again mysql. If it doesnt work you need to completily reinstall mysql
This happens when you ungracefully kill the mysql process normally.
Did you rebooted centos withouth doing?

```
systemctl stop mysql
```